# having trouble with CSS and jquery UI draggable

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm far from a CSS guru and am having an issue trying to drag elements from a container at the top with position:fixed to the main content of the page. It is just scrolling down the top container instead of dragging into the main content. Its difficult to explain so I made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wG5t/11/

As you can see, you can't drag any elements from the top into the main body of the page. Also, in the actual page there are a lot of elements in the top section so I need to maintain the horizontal scrollbar. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Also here's the code from the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="fieldSectionContainer">
<div class="fieldSection">
    <ul id="fieldList">
        <!-- have loop here -->
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>
        <li class="fieldClass">field value</li>

    </ul>


</div>
</div>


<div style="margin-top:100px">
    content below <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>
    content below  <br/><br/>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fieldClass {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:4px;
    width:200px;
    margin:5px 5px;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;      
}

.fieldClass:hover {
    cursor:move;
 }

 .fieldSectionContainer {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
 }

 .fieldSection {

    height:100px;
    width:2500px;   
    font-size:10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide a `droppable` zone for a `draggable` element. And then it will only accept the dragged element.

Give an id to your last division, and make it an `draggalbe` zone.

Have a look at this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wG5t/12/)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that appendTo: body part is what stops it from from scrolling in the top area and allows you to drag it into the bottom area is that correct?

Comment: Also apparently the helper:clone part is necessary as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you put revert to true the box will just move back to its original position.
What are you trying to do?

Your scripts are not yet finish.. If you have a draggable element then you must have a drop function as well..

Have you look for tutorials?..
Here's a link to [jquery drag and drop functionality](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Or look at this same [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263266/when-drag-a-object-from-one-div-to-another-format-gets-changed)..
But the thread is not yet solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the horizontal scroll.

The following has also been changed:

before-> revert: true
after -> revert: false

You can check it jsfiddle.net/4wG5t/13/

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately losing the horizontal scroll doesn't allow the user to scroll to see the rest of field boxes at the top. That was part of my issue.